# No error...search function still not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a code for a program that will show pictures that are accessible from the main menu. In my menu, there is a search option that opens a new window in which you can search through the database (that's a list) and if the entered words are in the list it will activate a function. the search function is shown in this part of code:

```
def search():
    def compare(words):
        key=words.get()
        print(key)
        for i in base:
            if i==key:
                if key=="apple":
                    AppleFunction()

                if key=="pear":
                    PearFunction()
                else:
                    messagebox.showerror("Eror!","Wrong entry, please correct!")
        return
    searchWindow=Toplevel(main)
    searchWindow.geometry("425x125+225+145")
    searchWindow.resizable(False,False)
    searchWindow.config(bg=mycolor)
    searchWindow.title("Search")
    searchWindow.iconbitmap(r"f.ico")

    words=Entry(searchWindow)
    words.config(font="Times", width=20)

    text1=Label(searchWindow, text="Search by key words:", wraplength=250, justify="center")
    text1.pack(pady=5)
    text1.config(bg=mycolor, font="Times")
    words.pack(pady=5)

    picture1=PhotoImage(file="ttt.gif")
    searchButton=Button(searchWindow, image=picture1, height=19)
    searchButton.config(bg=mycolor)
    searchButton.bind("<Button>", compare(words))
    searchButton.pack(pady=5)

    searchWindow.mainloop()
    return
```

It is all made with Tkinter module. I tried with global variables and arguments with functions, but there was no error. Although there is no error, the program still doesn't work. Can someone help me solve the problem?

Comment: What *is* the problem? What does *"doesn't work"* mean?

Comment: this is a bad question: Your code is unclear, your variables are named in a foreign language that probably make sense to you, but make it hard for us to help you. It's unclear what you are trying to do and what doesn't work. start by creating a minimal working example. If you get an error in your minimal example, post both the code of the minimal example and the error. If you don't get an error in your example, find what you did different in your real code. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example

Comment: @polo note that `[mcve]` in a comment is expanded to: [mcve].

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Often, if code runs and nothing happens and there is no error, that means you have a conditional statement that you assume should be passing but is not. Have you verified the values and types being used in the `if` statement are actually what you assume they are? What is stored in `baza`? Is it a list of strings, a list of numbers, or a list of objects?

Comment: I created a program that has a Menu. Under that menu is an option "Search" which when a user clicks on it, starts a function that creates a new window with an Entry and Button. When the user writes words in the Entry and presses the button, it triggers the inner function in the one that creates the window to compare the words that the user wrote with a list of strings. If there is a congruence in strings it will active a new certain function that is visible here. When I run the program it doesn't do so, but it also has no error. I will translate it to English so it can be easier to understand.

Comment: alright, so I change it to English. Does it help? I will try to write it again from scratch, but this the third time. Usual errors were with global variables or function arguments, but when I solve those problems it just doesn't work what it should and no error is shown.

Comment: alright, I fixed the problem, the inner function was missing "event" as the argument, but there is another problem: when the program closes, a message box pops out and a random blank window. Tried to move that away but haven't succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved the problem by making the Entry global and giving the inner function that compares the strings the "event" argument. Here is the correct code:

```
def search():
    def compare(event):
        key=str(words.get())
        for i in base:
            if i==key:
                if key=="Apple":
                    AppleFunction()

                elif key=="Pear":
                    PearFunction()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error!","Wrong entry, please correct!")
        return
    searchWindow=Toplevel(main)
    searchWindow.geometry("425x125+225+145")
    searchWindow.resizable(False,False)
    searchWindow.config(bg=mycolor)
    searchWindow.title("Tražilica")
    searchWindow.iconbitmap(r"f.ico")

    text1=Label(searchWindow, text="Search by key words:", wraplength=250, justify="center")
    text1.pack(pady=5)
    text1.config(bg=mycolor, font="Times")

    global words
    words=Entry(searchWindow)
    words.config(font="Times", width=20)
    words.pack(pady=5)

    picture1=PhotoImage(file="ttt.gif")
    searchButtton=Button(searchWindow, image=picture1, height=19)
    searchButtton.config(bg=mycolor)
    searchButtton.bind("<Button>", trazi)
    searchButttonb.pack(pady=5)

    searchWindow.mainloop()
    return
```

Although, when I exit the program, it shows me the error message that I created for a case when the string doesn't match and opens a random new empty Tkinter window which shouldn't be happening because while the program was running it has found by keywords correctly what I was looking for and gave me the correct picture. Also, There was this error on the Console (but not in Shell):

invalid command name ".!toplevel.!button"
    while executing
"$w cget -relief"
    (procedure "tk::ButtonDown" line 9)
    invoked from within
"tk::ButtonDown .!toplevel.!button"
    (command bound to event)